# CHECK IF JOIN IS SUCCESSFUL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm creating an oracle query which will insert an information on a column to a target table to check if the left join of 2 other tables is successful. Part of the process is to check join result using 3 different IDs.

```
Target - Table3.JoinCheck 

Joining Table (Source 1 and 2)
Source1 - Table1.Key1,
          Table1.Key2,
          Table1.Key3

Source2 - Table2.Key1
```

I would like to do a left Join using table 1 and 2 on table1.key1 = table2.key1, table1.key2 = table2.key1, table1.key3 = table2.key1. If any of these join is successful it returns 'OK' to Table3.JoinCheck. If unsuccessful, I want to return the following error message:'table1.key1 = table2.key1 not matched','table1.key2 = table2.key1 not matched' ,  'table1.key3 = table2.key1 not matched'

```
INSERT INTO table3 (JoinCheck) c 
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN a.key1 IS NOT NULL
             OR a.key2 IS NOT NULL
             OR a.key3 IS NOT NULL
           THEN 'OK'
         CASE
           WHEN a.key1 IS NULL
           THEN 'table1.key1 = table2.key1 not matched'
         CASE 
           WHEN a.key2 IS NULL
           THEN 'table1.key2 = table2.key1 not matched'
         CASE
           WHEN a.key3 IS NULL
           THEN 'table1.key3 = table2.key1 not matched'
         END AS Joincheck
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.key1 = b.key1
    OR a.key2 = b.key1
    OR a.key3 = b.key1
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do using what level of software. "check if" & "return the following error message" are vague. Please clarify. PS Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CASE expression is incorrect and won't execute. Try

```
INSERT INTO table3 (JoinCheck) c 
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN a.key1 IS NOT NULL
               OR a.key2 IS NOT NULL
               OR a.key3 IS NOT NULL
             THEN 'OK'
           WHEN a.key1 IS NULL
             THEN 'table1.key1 = table2.key1 not matched'
           WHEN a.key2 IS NULL
             THEN 'table1.key2 = table2.key1 not matched'
           WHEN a.key3 IS NULL
             THEN 'table1.key3 = table2.key1 not matched'
         END AS Joincheck
  FROM table1 a
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.key1 = b.key1
    OR a.key2 = b.key1
    OR a.key3 = b.key1
```

Also if any of `table1.key1`, `table1.key2`, `table1.key3`, or `table2.key` are NULL the OR comparisons in your ON clause will fail because any comparison with NULL returns NULL rather than TRUE or FALSE. You may need to ensure that these values aren't NULL when being compared. Perhaps something like

```
  LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON NVL(a.key1, -1) = NVL(b.key1, -2)
    OR NVL(a.key2, -1) = NVL(b.key1, -2)
    OR NVL(a.key3, -1) = NVL(b.key1, -2)
```

This assumes that none of your key values can be -1 or -2 - if not, choose other values.

Comment: Hi Bob, I'm not sure if it's proper to use LEFT JOIN for this case. I believe using such will always  return unmatched values for key1, key2, key3 from table 1, which actually defeats the purpose of CASE WHEN statement.